# How can I use actual screen heigth in a ConverterParameter?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

```
     <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
      Height = "<Get current Height - some layout pixels>"
      Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, 
      ConverterParameter=<Get current Height - some layout pixels>" />
```

I want to calculate  Height and Width of the image before image is loaded. How to pass current screen Height to `ConverterParameter`?

UPDATED: It is possible to use `Window.Current.Bounds.Height` in `IValueConverter` so there is no need now to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConverterParameter is not a dependency property in silverlight.

Firstly check if is it a dependency property for WinRT. If it is not a dependency property you can't use binding.

As I see you are trying to stretch something. Maybe "ViewBox" class exists for your area,if so you put a control inside your ViewBox it automatically stretches.

Comment: So "ConverterParameter IS NOT a depency property but a “simple” object in XAML".